# mongodb, get the result line after update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I'm working with mongodb, node.js and socket.io and I'm trying to reduce the number off access to the database. I need to update a line ; and after to return the updated line this is how I do :

```
db.collection('users').update({_id:targetID}, {$set: { 'property': 'value' }}, {safe:true}, function(err, result) {
    db.collection('users').find({_id:targetID}).toArray(function(error, results){
        //a socket.io resend the content
    });
});
```

It works, but I really fell like I'm having a useless step here. The callback of the update function seems to be a boolean.

BTW, is there a better documentation than this one : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update/ ? I'd like to find a list of properties and methods. The `{safe:true}` for instance. It seems not working without it but I can't find it in the reference.

Maybe I'm completely wrong and this is not the way I should do it. If you have a better idea... :)

Comment: what do you mean by "safe:true" seems not working?

Comment: I wrote : "It seems not working without it ". So yes, it is working, but I don't know what it does.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`findAndModify`](http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#findandmodify) to do this efficiently:

```
db.collection('users').findAndModify(
    {_id: targetID}, [], 
    {$set: { 'property': 'value' }}, 
    {new: true}, // Return the updated doc rather than the original
    function(err, result) {
        // result contains the updated document
    }
);
```

Comment: You're my savior ! I could not figure out how to read the documentation... findAndModify and findAndRemove are going to help me sooooo much :)